# My practicing with PHP sqrt does not work

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, primes

I'm practicing algorithms creating the fastest possible prime generator I can think off. This is the working code I have up to date:

```
    $p = array();
    function isPrime($i) {
        global $p;
        $s = $i / 2;
        foreach ($p as $n) {
            if ($n >= $s) return true;
            if ($i % $n == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 3, $k = 20000; $i <= $k; $i += 2) {
        isPrime($i) and $p[] = $i;
    }
    echo(microtime(true) - $start);
```

But then I realized I could optimize `$s = $i / 2;` to `$s = sqrt($i);`, which would test less numbers. When I tested, the code fails and gets every number as a prime. Essentially que sqrt fails and always returns true.

What the heck is happening?

Comment: Instead of optimizing your code you should optimize your algorithm. The Sieve of Eratosthenes will be far faster than the trial division that you are using.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to get farthest possible, like benchmarking the code, and from what I've read of the Sieve of Era~ it's not like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this statement

```
$s = $i / 2;
```

Stores half value of `$i` variable in `$s` and this statement

```
$s = sqrt($i);
```

stores square root of `$i` in `$s`

## Rectified code

```
$p = array();
function isPrime($i) {
    global $p;
    //$s = $i / 2;
    $s = sqrt($i);
    foreach ($p as $n) {
        if ($n > $s) return true;  // The condition here should be $n > $s not $n >= $s
        if ($i % $n == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 3, $k = 20000; $i <= $k; $i += 2) {
    isPrime($i) and $p[] = $i;
}
//echo(microtime(true) - $start);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($p);
```

[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lcOiz2)

## Output

```
 Array
(
[0] => 3
[1] => 5
[2] => 7
[3] => 11
[4] => 13
[5] => 17
[6] => 19
[7] => 23
[8] => 29
[9] => 31
.......
```

Comment: I'm starting to think the server of my university is very messed up, haha. Your code is right, I will test when possible.

Comment: @ranisalt You can test the fiddle...:)